# The type javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader is not accessible (vscode)

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, javafx

so i've been working on a Maven Project which supports JavaFX. I tried to use javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader, but i couldn't, since "FXMLLoader cannot be resolved". I tried fixing Maven dependencies (since javafx.fxml didn't showed up) but it just didn't work.

This is my main:

[4: The type javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader is not accessible

20: FXMLLoader cannot be resolved][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wH8V.png)

Hope somebody can help me, thanks!

Comment: make sure you added the module javafx.fxml

Comment: I mean i thought i did, check https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wH8V.png

Comment: Edit the question and add the full text of your `module-info.java` in which you require the `javafx.fxml` module, and also add the full text of your `pom.xml` where you specify dependencies for `javafx-fxml` and other javafx modules.

Comment: Do not screenshot code, edit the question and put the code as text formatted as code in the question AND the error messages, also as text formatted as code.  See: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section titled "Help others reproduce the problem".

Answer (score 0):

**Referenced Libraries** is for no build tools project. You use Maven, dependency is the right option instead of jars.

Add the following in `pom.xml`, then extension will notice you to synchronize configuration.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
    <version>18-ea+8</version>
</dependency>
```

You can check the existed dependencies from **Maven--> Dependencies** in the left:
[image]